# ace editor ace-build and ace-build-master folder issue

Tags: ace-editor

I am trying to work with text highlighter in ACE editor.

I put ace-builds-master folder into my project 
Looking at documentations it says that All Ace modes can be found in the lib/ace/mode folder.
I could not find that folder.
After downloading ace-master folder from github and working with it all I got was error defined is not defined. couldn't solve that either also after inserting requireJS.js file etc., so I removed that folder and I am back to the beginning.

Also what is the difference between ace-build and ace-build-master since after trying to work only with ace-master folder nothing works while ace-builds-master does??

I need a simple explanation what to do, since neither of documentation manuals does not work

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two versions
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace which have `lib/ace/mode` folder
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds which is a concatenated version of previous one and all modes are in `mode-*` files